# Why root makes phone fast

Tags: rooting, root-access

I have heard many sites saying that  rooting makes phone faster but in technical detail it just increase process and more process = slow phone so why people say it

Example : we have phone   *A*  and phone  *B*   *A*  is rooted and  *B*  is not but   *A*  runs without any root apps so which will be fast (*according to sites A will be fast*)

Comment: Just remember that root in itself cannot make a device fast. Root unlocks the potential of tuning your phone (by remove bloat etc) which can make the phone fast. This may not apply to phones which don't have a lot of bloat or apps installed in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways that having root *may* improve performance. But just rooting won't make a phone faster.

- One common thing to do with a rooted phone is to remove "bloat" apps. These are apps that are installed by default. In recent versions of android, you can "freeze" or "Turn Off" more built-in apps, making root less of a requirement for de-bloating. [Here's a guide for those without without root](http://forums.androidcentral.com/ambassador-guides-tips-how-s/325138-guide-how-disable-apps.html). With root, your best bet is to find a guide in the specific forum for your phone on [XDA Developers](http://xda-developers.com) or a similar site. These will include other users' experience about what is safe to remove or disable.
- There used to be a lot of types of apps that could tune the memory management with the goal of improved performance or longer battery life, but I haven't seen them recently. Modern phones often have a lot more ram (2 or more GB) than they used to.
- Another thing that a rooted phone with a specific kernel can do is overclock the processor. This is complex and potentially dangerous (could crash or cause physical damage to the phone by overheating), but may be useful for older phones with slower processors.
- Installing a custom ROM may also make the phone run faster, depending on a lot of factors about the specific phone and the specific ROM.
- There are also many specific fixes for individual phones that can improve performance.
- Ad blockers can speed up web browsing (as well as make the phone more secure). Most of these require root as they install `hosts` redirects, although there are some that appear as a VPN and should work without root.

Comment: Can you point a resource on removing bloatware and useless stuff with root access? Whatever could be removed via regular user was already removed on my two devices.

Comment: Oh, you said *with* root. Unfortunately, it's going to depend on the specific phone.

Answer (score 2):

Rooting your device does not make it "faster".
It allows you to remove pre-installed "bloatware" that is pushed by manufacturers and their partners. Adittionally rooting permits you to remove, deactivate non-essential process and functions that free up ram as well.
Rooting also allows you to tweak your device performance through init.d scripts custom kernels and dumping and modifying your boot.img to "kill" even more unecessary process and manufacturer impositions. You should absolutely do the research on your specific device to be sure of what you can get rid of, or you will end up soft bricking or hard bricking your device.
Rooting your device enables you to make your device "faster" .

Answer (score 1):

Simply rooting your phone won't make it run faster. You can use root access to tweak your phone to run faster. Here I'll make a short list of how tos

1. By removing bloatwares
2. Changing and customizing CPU governors and I/O scheduler
3. Flashing custom roms or kernels
4. Editing System configuration files such as build.prop

etc. You can find many more ways to tweak your phone to make it run faster, just use Google.

A rooted phone can run faster than an unrooted one only if you tweak it properly.

Comment: Can you point a resource that describes build.prop in details? I have already changed a config in there following a tutorial, but I want to learn what those options mean.

Comment: @LucasSoares Use titanium backup

Comment: There are no detailed tutorial explaining every line in build.prop AFIK. The best you can find is what build.prop is and some good tweaks. You can find plenty articles if you search for them with Google. But be warned, you may end up soft bricking you phone if you don't know what you're doing. So keeping a nandroid backup before you do anything is very important. Good luck.

Comment: @User8989 Yeah, I'm more interested in understanding how Android works than on editing the build.prop myself. I have a good grasp on traditional OSes, but smartphones look alien to me.

Comment: @LucasSoares the build.prop contains key-value pairs which describe various core device system-level settings. No wonder it expands to*Build Properties*. Individual options available differ by model, chipset, and Android version.